# Obj-C enum redefinition error

Tags: objective-c, enums

```
typedef enum {
    artists = 0,
    artists_songs = 1,
    artist_albums = 2,
    albums = 3,
    album_songs = 4,
    tags = 5,
    tag = 6,
    tag_artists = 7,
    tag_albums = 8,
    tag_songs = 9,
    songs = 10,
    song = 11,
    playlists = 12,
    playlist = 13,
    playlist_songs = 14,
    search_songs = 15
} Methods;

typedef enum {
    artists = 0,
    albums = 1,
    songs = 2,
    tags = 3,
    playlists = 4    
} ReturnTypes;
```

I keep getting an error on the artists = 0 line for ReturnTypes, saying that artists has been re-declared. I'm not sure what the syntax error on this is. Any ideas?

Comment: remove `artists` from any one enum definition, it says duplicate declaration of `artist` constant in your application.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The syntax error is that `artists` is being redeclared! You've declared it once in the first enum, now you're trying to declare it again in the second line. These enums are not separate types; they are just lists of constants. You can't have two constants called `artists`.

This is why enums in Cocoa have obnoxiously long boring names, such as `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`. It is so that they won't clash with one another. You should do the same, e.g. `MyMethodsArtists` vs. `MyReturnTypesArtists`.

Comment: WOW, Obj-C doesn't differentiate? I can't do like Methods.artists or ReturnTypes.artists?

Comment: The `NS_ENUM` macro, new in LLVM 4.0, improves things a little bit, allowing the compiler to do something a bit more like type checking on enumerations, but the global namespace problem remains.

Comment: @RyanCopley: C does not have namespaces, unfortunately. The normal hack is to use a prefix on the identifier (e.g. `return_artists` or `rt_artists`).

Answer (score 0):

You have "artists" in both your enum types. The compiler doesn't care whether they have the same value or not, it throws an error.

Try redefining one of the two. You'll have the same problem for all other redefined constants.

Answer (score 0):

An `enum` is just syntactic sugar for integer constants.  You cannot define a given identifier in more than one place; in this case, you are trying to have the same names in multiple enums.
You could try something like classes with static members (rough illustration, not tested code):

```
@implementation MethodsEnum

+(int)artists
{
    return 0;
}

+(int)artists_songs
{
    return 1;
}

// etc.

@end

@implementation ReturnTypeEnum

+(int)artists
{
    return 0;
}

+(int)albums
{
    return 1;
}

// etc.

@end
```

Note that I am *not recommending* this approach, but it does emulate some of the language features you seem to be missing from Java's `enum`.